# Which collection class to use for a rolling period timeseries of data?

Tags: c#, performance, collections, time-series

I want to imlpement a c# class (.NET 4.6.1) which contains time series data as follows :

- the timeseries is a collection keyed on DateTime, each with an associated value (eg an array of doubles)
- the points will be added strictly in time order
- there will be a rolling time period - e.g. 1 hour - when adding a new point, any points at the start older than this period will be removed
- the key issues for performance will be quickly adding new points, and finding the data point for a particular time (a binary search or better is essential). There will be 100k's of points in the collection sometimes.
- it has to be thread safe
- it has to be relatively memory efficient - e.g. it can't just keep all the points from the beginning of time - as time moves on the memory footprint has to be fairly stable.

So what would be a good approach for that in terms of underlying collection classes? Using Lists will be slow - as the rolling period means we will need to remove from the start of the List a lot. A Queue or LinkedList would solve that - but I don't think they provide a fast way to access the nth item in the collection (ElementAt just iterates so is very slow).

The only solution I can think of will involve storing the data twice - once in a collection thats easy to remove from the start of - and again in one thats easy to search in (with some awful background process to prune the stale points from the search collection somehow).

Is there a better way to approach this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would List be slow, remove item at end should be O(1)

Comment: But to prune the stale data I will have to remove items from the start of the List - which I believe is slow when the list is large.

Comment: My bad - it's O(Count) not O(count) :-)

Comment: You might want to look in to [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319(v=vs.110).aspx), you will just need to wrap it up with a [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) on every read or write access to make it thread safe.

Comment: The trouble with SortedList is that its also slow to remove items from the start of the list - ie its O(n) - so very slow when there are 100k+ items in the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I first saw the question I immediately thought of a queue, but most built-in queues do not efficiently allow indexed access, as you've found.

Best suggestion I can come up with is to use a ConcurrentDictionary. Thread-safe, near-constant access time by key, you can key directly to DateTimes, etc. it's everything you need functionally, *except* the behavior to manage size/timeline. To do that, you use a little Linq to scan the Keys property for keys more than one hour older than the newest one being added, then TryRemove() each one (you can derive from ConcurrentDictionary and override TryAdd() to do this automatically when adding anything new).

Only other potential issue is it's not terribly memory-efficient; the HashSet-based implementation of .NET Dictionaries requires a two-dimensional array for storage based on the hash of the key, and that array will be sparsely populated even with 100k items in the collection.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - I'll give ConcurrentDictionary a try. I will probably have to keep a seperate collection of the keys - since I want to also be able to lookup on not exact key values and return the previous value. However this will be a lot better than my previous idea.

Comment: The Keys collection in the Dictionary is essentially a ReadOnlyCollection; you can do Linq queries and other list-based read operations on it, including finding the maximum key value less than an example timestamp. It's thread-safe, but to do that, they have to clone the actual Dictionary's key array, so operations made on the "fringes" of the expected key values may not be reliable if you're constantly inserting and deleting keys in other threads.

Comment: I thought referencing Keys on a dictionary would involve creating a new collection of the keys from scratch each time? If not this would be perfect. Can you confirm this isn't what it does?

Comment: That is essentially what it does; the Keys property returns an `ICollection<TKey>` generated by cloning the underlying Dictionary's Keys property. It's the fastest and easiest way to make this operation thread-safe. To come up with something better, you'll have to implement a locking system that allows multiple enumerations of a collection in-place but blocks on concurrent access to each element. That will inevitably produce deadlocks when different threads enumerate the collection at different speeds or in different orders, which you'll have to detect and resolve.

Comment: If you really need to do all that, I would recommend interfacing with a database engine; SQLite or just an instance of SQL Server Express would be more efficient and concurrency-tolerant than anything you could come up with in the next week of development. Write a simple class to perform the tasks you need, which will interface with the SQL engine to do those things, and you're done.